# Vector of Maps in C++

Tags: c++

I am interested in creating a vector of maps. For example:

```
typedef map <int, map <string, string>> sent ;
vector <sent> variable1;
```

But, I am unsure on how to insert the map of maps as a vector of elements. I was hoping I could create a dictionary of dictionaries in python? Would the example above be OK for doing that? Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Why would you name a type `variable`?

Comment: Please elaborate.  Are you trying to insert "map<int, map<string,string>>" elements into the vector?  Are you trying to insert "map<string,string>" elements into a "map<int,  string,string>>"?  There seem to be many levels of indirection here, and your questions needs to be fleshed out a bit more.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: You should elaborate in further questions as to what you need to do, and possibly give some pseudo-code if not ACTUAL code. It makes it a lot easier to help you with your problem. My answer is what I believe the problem is asking, but again, I don't know if it is what you are looking for. If you update your question, feel free to leave a comment and I can improve my answer to better suit the question.

Comment: @BTownTKD Yes, Im trying to create insert a map <int, map <string, string> elements into a vector

Answer (score 1):

If you took a look at the manual page for vector, you would note that there is a push_back function. From there, you will need to do a push_back with a type of variable. So here is some sample code:

```
variable a;
map<string, string> b;
b["foo"] = "bar";
a[0] = b;
variable1.push_back(a);
```

Now, I don't quite understand WHY you need this, but here are my references:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of what is what.

```
typedef map <int, map <string, string>> PlentyOfmaps;
vector <PlentyOfMaps> moarMaps(1); // One map to start with.
moarMaps[0][21]["very"] = "confusing";
PlentyOfMaps suchMaps;
suchMaps[90000]["random data"] = "not so random akcherly";
moarMaps.push_back(suchMaps);
moarMaps[1][97][moarMaps[0][21]["very"]] = "it gets worse";
moarMaps.resize(1234); // Add 1232 empty maps.
```

But such deep levels of maps are usually a sign that it's time for a redesign, possibly encapsulating the collections in less generic classes.